# parameter value does not match expected type, except yes it does

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

im getting IllegalArgumentException but I don't think I should, here's the method:

```
public List<TimbratureOfDay> getTimbratureOfMonth(int year,String month,Long idEmployee);
```

and here's where I use it:

```
List<TimbratureOfDay> timbratureOfMonth = timbratureDAO.getTimbratureOfMonth(timeSheetInsertDTO.getAnno(), mese, idEmp);
```

it expects the second argument to be an integer for some reason, I don't know what to do

Comment: How do you initialize your variables?

Comment: the first is from an object gotten from an http request, the second one is declared as a string and initialized to null, if the mont value from the same object as the year is less than 10 then I give it the value of "0"+the month the if was based on,if not it's just String.valueOf the month, the third one is fetched from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

in the query I had to cast the month into a char so that the expected type becomes string.